# Set exam time 30 minutes by Javascript error?

Tags: javascript, php

I am writing for web exam page ,in there I have to set 30 minutes to exam time.So I used `onload` and `settimeout` function to check if 30 minutes over,the question page is close and go to finish page.I want to add current minutes 30.But it's doesn't work,don't go to `finish.php`.!

```
<body onload="time()">
  <!-- question code -->
<div id="time"></div><!-- show time  -->
</body>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
function time(){
var j = new Date();
var hr = j.getHours();
var sec = j.getSeconds();
var min = j.getMinutes();
var m = min + 30;//set 30 minutes exam times
if (m === min) {
    location.href = "finish.php";
}    
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
 setTimeout(function() {
    time()
 }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please include a jsfiddle of your code

Comment: why not just _setTimeout(function() {
    location.href = "finish.php";
 }, 30*60*1000);_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function time() {
    var time = 60 * 1;  //Replace 1 with 30 minutes
    var minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
      minutes = parseInt(time / 60)
      seconds = parseInt(time % 60);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
       
      time--;
      
      if (time < 0) {
        location.href = "finish.php";
      }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="time()">
  <!-- question code -->
<div id="time"></div><!-- show time  -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
function time(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = "finish.php";
    }, 30*60*1000);
    setInterval(function() {
       var j = new Date();
       var hr = j.getHours();
       var min = j.getMinutes();
       var sec = j.getSeconds();
       document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    }, 1000);
 }
```

Comment: well,  UI has is being updated evey one second `document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;`

Comment: it's doesn't work for time display (setInterval),setTimeout is worked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your are assigning new value to `m`  every timeout. you should initialize, `m` only once.

also `minute` goes from `0-59`   so you cant always check for it is equal to `m + 30`, thats wrong way of doing it

being said that its always better to do this timeout at server side, at client side there are enough ways to cheat around it